# Vite / Ruby not rendering Vue Page

Tags: ruby, vue.js, vite

I'm using Ruby 2.5.9 with Rails 4.2.11.3 at my project and try to get my Vue Frontend connected to it by using Vite. So I installed:

```
vite_ruby: 3.0.7
vite_rails_legacy: 3.0.3
vite: 2.7.12
```

regarding the docs. The vite.json looks like this:

```
{
  "all": {
    "sourceCodeDir": "frontend",
    "watchAdditionalPaths": []
  },
  "development": {
    "autoBuild": true,
    "publicOutputDir": "vite-dev",
    "port": 3036,
   "host": "127.0.0.1"
  },
  "test": {
    "autoBuild": true,
    "publicOutputDir": "vite-test"
  }
}
```

When now visiting the frontend I keep getting the error message:

`http://localhost:3000/vite-dev/@id/vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js/server-renderer net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probolem was `@vitejs/plugin-vue` not properly being installed by yarn. So a manual installation of it solved the problem. Also it must be included inside the `vite.config.js` like: `import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'`.